# Laravel 8 Livewire Save ID of Selected Value in Drop Down

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I have two tables in my database **"emp_info" contains(user_id, firstname, lastname)** and **"load_schedule" contains(faculty_id, corsname, day, room, time).**
The problem is I have an edit modal(pop-up) which is included in my main view although it displays the list of instructors **($instructors)** but it can't update the faculty_id column with the new selected value.

**Tried this so far:**

```
<select class="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" name="faculty_id">
    <option value="selected:" selected></option>
    @foreach($instructors as $emp)
        <option value="{{ $emp->user_id }}">{{ $emp->firstname.' '.$emp->lastname }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

---

As you can see I am trying to use the user_id value to be inserted in the faculty_id column. Am I doing it wrong?
**I did put $instructors as global array in AppServiceProviders**

---

Controller Codes

```
class JoinTable extends Component
{
    use WithPagination;
    public $faculty_id,$firstname,$lastname,$fullnames,$emp_id,$emp,$appointmentid,$corsno,$corsdes,$day,$c_time,$hours,$room,$section,$size,$sem,$sy,$unit,$userid,$user_id;
    public $openEdit=0;


    public function render() 
    {
        $dupeSchedules = DB::table('load_schedule')
        ->select('room', 'hours', 'day','sy','sem')
        ->groupBy('room', 'hours', 'day','sy','sem')
        ->havingRaw('COUNT(*) > 1');
        //Sub-Query for isolating duplicated schedules//
        $dupliSchedules=DB::table('load_schedule')
        ->join('emp_info', 'load_schedule.faculty_id', '=','emp_info.user_id')
        ->select('load_schedule.*', 'emp_info.firstname', 'emp_info.lastname')
        ->joinSub($dupeSchedules, 'dupe_schedules', function ($join) {
        $join->on('load_schedule.room','=', 'dupe_Schedules.room');
        $join->on('load_schedule.day','=', 'dupe_Schedules.day');
        $join->on('load_schedule.hours','=', 'dupe_Schedules.hours');
        $join->on('load_schedule.sy','=', 'dupe_Schedules.sy');
        $join->on('load_schedule.sem','=', 'dupe_Schedules.sem');
        })->paginate(10);
    
        return view('livewire.join-table',compact('dupliSchedules'));
    }

    public function edit($id)
    {
        $emp=Emp_sched::findorFail($id);
        $this->emp_id=$emp->id;
        $this->faculty_id=$emp->faculty_id;
        $this->corsno=$emp->corsno;
        $this->corsdes=$emp->corsdes;
        $this->day=$emp->day;
        $this->c_time=$emp->c_time;
        $this->hours=$emp->hours;
        $this->room=$emp->room;
        $this->section=$emp->section;
        $this->size=$emp->size;
        $this->sem=$emp->sem;
        $this->sy=$emp->sy;
        $this->unit=$emp->unit;
        $this->user_id=$emp->user_id;
    
        $this->editModal();
    }
    
    public function editModal(){
        $this->openEdit=true;
    }
    
    public function closeModal(){
        $this->openEdit=false;
    }
    
    public function store(){
        
        $this->validate([
            'corsdes'=>'required',
            'c_time'=>'required'
        ]);
        
        Emp_sched::updateOrCreate(['id'=>$this->emp_id],[
        'user_id'=>$this->user_id,
        'faculty_id'=>$this->faculty_id,
        'corsno'=>$this->corsno,
        'corsdes'=>$this->corsdes,
        'day'=>$this->day,
        'c_time'=>$this->c_time,
        'hours'=>$this->hours,
        'room'=>$this->room,
        'section'=>$this->section,
        'size'=>$this->size,
        'sem'=>$this->sem,
        'sy'=>$this->sy,
        'unit'=>$this->unit
        ]);
        
         session()->flash('message', 
            $this->emp_id ? 'Updated Successfully.' : 'Created Successfully.');
        
        $this->closeModal();
        $this->resetCreateForm();
    }
    
    public function create(){
        $this->editModal();
    }
    
    public function delete($id){
 
            Emp_sched::findorFail($id)->delete();
         session()->flash('warning',  'Deleted Successfully.');
        
        $this->closeModal();
    }
    private function resetCreateForm()

    {
        $this->user_id='';
        $this->faculty_id= '';
        $this->corsno= '';
        $this->corsdes= '';
        $this->day= '';
        $this->c_time= '';
        $this->hours= '';
        $this->room= '';
        $this->section= '';
        $this->size= '';
        $this->sem= '';
        $this->sy= '';
        $this->unit= '';
        $this->userid= '';
    }


}  
***************************************************
```

Comment: i want to see your controller method and models, can you update your question.

Comment: I have updated the questions but i cant seem to add the codes for the models tried Ctrl+K but its just not formatting. Im so sorry.

Comment: I did put the faculty_id as fillable

Comment: Tried dumping the value on select Yeah it shows the id value but its just not updating.

Comment: Thanks for your  help from you two I have resolve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an another solution, You didn't posted your controller and model to here is example.

```html
protected $fillable = [

        'faculty_id', 'corsname', 'day', 'room', 'time'
    ];
```

Above code will be in  you model. If your controller codes are fine
You select should be like this.

```
<select class="" name="faculty_id" id="faculty_id" >
```

Here is an example

```html
 <select class="form-control" name="roles" id="roles" required="">
                 <option value="0" selected="" disabled="">Select Role</option> 
                  @foreach ($roles as $role)
                    
                      <option value="{{$role->id}}" @if($roleid==$role->id) selected @endif>{{$role->name}}</option> 
                        
             
                   
                  @endforeach
                </select>
```

Try this bellow code If your controller and model are good

```
<option name ="faculty_id" value="{{ $emp->user_id }}">{{ $emp->firstname.' '.$emp->lastname }}</option>
```

I adding here someones suggestion to help people, if you are in a Livewire component the select element must be bind to the backend property.

```
<select class="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" wire:model="faculty_id">
 <option value=""></option>
 @foreach($instructors as $emp)
    <option value="{{ $emp->user_id }}">{{ $emp->firstname.' '.$emp->lastname }}</option>
 @endforeach
</select>
```

then in the livewire component

```
public $faculty_id;

...///...

public function updatedFacultyId($value)
{
    dd($value); // on select change, this line must be dumped
}
```

Comment: i added @prospero suggestion to my answer. thanks man for reviewing.

Answer (score 0):

after check the steps in the class model of Ronny answer, if you are in a Livewire component the select element must be bind to the backend property.

```
<select class="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" wire:model="faculty_id">
 <option value=""></option>
 @foreach($instructors as $emp)
    <option value="{{ $emp->user_id }}">{{ $emp->firstname.' '.$emp->lastname }}</option>
 @endforeach
</select>
```

then in the livewire component

```
public $faculty_id;

...///...

public function updatedFacultyId($value)
{
    dd($value); // on select change, this line must be dumped
}
```